# relations between topology and organic chemistry

Tags: organic-chemistry, molecular-structure

I am a Ph.D student studying  topology and geometry (in mathematics). I find a lot of references giving applications of geometric & combinatorial topology in organic chemistry. For example:

[Geometric and Topological Thinking in Organic Chemistry](http://turroserver.chem.columbia.edu/pdf_db/philosophy/379_angewtopology.pdf)

[Graphene, vortices and Graphene, vortices and
the index theorem the index theorem](http://www.int.washington.edu/talks/WorkShops/int_08_37W/People/Pachos_J/Pachos.pdf)

[On borromean links](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/liangmislow.pdf)

Is it possible for me to find a career in organic chemistry or organic chemical engeineering after graduation? If I want to do so, could you give me suggestions what background knowledge/textbooks should I learn?

Thanks!

Comment: @R. S. is right. If your question was about topology in chemistry and/or those links, it might fit better. But you qquestion is "*Is it possible for me to find a career...*" which isn't a chemistry question.